# How to get data to html using node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I got the data from the database connected to nodejs.
But I want to express the imported data in html file. What kind of work do you need?

my app.js code

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
    router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
      res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });  
      var cnt_visit ='SELECT COUNT(*) as totla_cnt FROM vistor_count where vistor_page = "main_index"'; 
      conn.query(cnt_visit, function (err, results, fields) { 
        console.log(results[0].totla_cnt);   
    }); 
    
    });
```

How to send results[0].totla_cnt to html file?

Comment: You would need to use one of many template engines to have you data blended into an html template file. From the `Express JS` website: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using template engines with Express

https://strongloop.com/strongblog/compare-javascript-templates-jade-mustache-dust/